# PHP dns_get_record long TXT record BUG

Tags: php, dns

When I try to get a `TXT` record that has a rather `long value` and the look-up returns the record split in two packets, `PHP stitches` the two packets together badly breaking the data with various characters.

Initially I discovered it added character `\x00` but now I noticed it added a tab `\t`.

Is there a way to clean-up the record ensuring `100% integrity` or another way of getting the record?

Comment: What is a TXT record?

Comment: It is a type of DNS record. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types